# Python dataframe find difference between min and max in a row

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe of many columns as given below

```
df = 

index  P1   Q1   W1  P2   Q2   W2  P3   Q3   W3 
0      1    -1    2  3    0   -4   -4   4    0  
1      2    -5    8  9    3   -7   -8   9    6 
2     -4    -5    3  4    5   -6   -7   8    8
```

I want to compute row wise difference between max and min in P columns.

```
df['P_dif'] =  max (P1,P2,P3) - min (P1,P2,P3)
```

My expected output

```
df = 

index  P1   Q1   W1  P2   Q2   W2  P3   Q3   W3    P_dif
0      1    -1    2  3    0   -4   -4   4    0      7   # 3-(-4)
1      2    -5    8  9    3   -7   -8   9    6      17  # 9-(-8)      
2     -4    -5    3  4    5   -6   -7   8    8      11  # 4-(-7)
```

My present code

```
df['P_dif'] = df[df.columns[::3]].apply(lambda g: g.max()-g.min())
```

My present output

```
print(df['P_dif'])
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

Comment: FYI, your first line of expected output is wrong since `P3` is `-4` rather than `4`. In other words, it would be `3-(-4) = 7`. That won't help with your `NaN`s, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @paxdiablo Corrected. Thanks for identifying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not *sure* why you're getting `Nan` values but I suspect it may be because you have rows with `NaN` in the `Px` columns (in the rows you hven't shown us in your example).

The *reason* I suspect this is because the lambda you're applying is operating on columns rather than rows, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> data = [[1,-1,2,3,0,-4,-4,4,0],[2,-5,8,9,3,-7,-8,9,6],[-4,-5,3,4,5,-6,-7,8,8]]
>>> df=pandas.DataFrame(data,columns=['P1','Q1','W1','P2','Q2','W2','P3','Q3','W3'])
>>> df
   P1  Q1  W1  P2  Q2  W2  P3  Q3  W3
0   1  -1   2   3   0  -4  -4   4   0
1   2  -5   8   9   3  -7  -8   9   6
2  -4  -5   3   4   5  -6  -7   8   8
>>> df[df.columns[::3]].apply(lambda g: g.max()-g.min())
P1    6 #  2 - -4 -> 6
P2    6 #  9 -  3 -> 6
P3    4 # -4 - -8 -> 4
```

Note the output specifying the `P1`, `P2` and `P3` values and the stuff I've added as comments to the right, to show that it's the maximal difference of the *column* rather than the row.

---

You can get the information you need with the following:

```
>>> numpy.ptp(numpy.array(df[['P1', 'P2', 'P3']]), axis=1)
array([7, 17, 11], dtype=int64)
```

I don't doubt someone more familar than I with Pandas and Numpy could improve on that so feel free to edit this answer if that's the case.

Comment: Some syntax error. Now your method is working for me. Thanks. On trial and error, I found this answer `df[df.columns[::3]].max(axis=1)-df[df.columns[::3]].min(axis=1)`. Is this a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.max](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html), [DataFrame.min](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) with `axis=1` to calculate `max` and `min` value among columns

```
computed_cols = df.loc[:, ['P1', 'P2', 'P3']]
df['P_dif'] = computed_cols.max(axis=1) - computed_cols.min(axis=1)
```

Best,